# JScript regex - extract a substring between 2 words containing 1 or more occurrences of another word

Tags: javascript, regex, jscript

I have a text extracted from a large PDF file. I am only interested in one part of this text. I only need the part which is present between 2 `test` substrings AND which has 1 or more occurrences of a specific word `XX12QW`. Out of those 2 `test` substrings/words, the first one can be included in the match as shown in the desired output below

**Input String:**

```
test 
abc def 
test 123 
test pqr 
XX12QW
jkl XX12QW hjas 
12asd23 test bxs
```

**Desired Output:**

```
test pqr 
XX12QW
jkl XX12QW hjas 
12asd23
```

**Things to be noted:**

- There are multiple occurrences of the substring `test`.
- I need only the part between 2 substrings/words - `test` which contain 1 or more occurrences of the word `XX12QW`. This word `XX12QW` will not be present at all between any **other** **pairs** of the word - `test`. That is, there will never be a case like this: `test abc XX12QW test isadkj XX12QW test an test`
- One extra test case would be if the word `XX12QW` is present between `test` and `$(End of string/file)`:

  - Input: `test absjh123 sjnc test jhsd32 test aabb XX12QW asdj XX12QW sdfk`
  - Desired Output: `test aabb XX12QW asdj XX12QW sdfk`

I am stuck on this for a long time now and really need someone else to look at it.

Regex: [`test[\s\S]*?XX12QW[\s\S]*?(?=test)`](https://regex101.com/r/leKxcO/2)

Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Assuming `test` is always the first in the string when used in an *open tag* sort of way, you can use `test(?!.*^test)(?=.*XX12QW).+(?=test)` with `sm` modifiers as show [here](https://regex101.com/r/u0LMvc/1). Another alternative is to use [`.*(test(?=.*XX12QW).+(?=test))`](https://regex101.com/r/u0LMvc/2), which stores the result into a capture group, this will only match the last occurrence, so assuming you have multiple occurrences, this will fail

Comment: Another option is [`test(?!.*test(?=.*test))(?=.*XX12QW).+(?=test)`](https://regex101.com/r/u0LMvc/3)

Comment: @ctwheels Thaks a ton. It is looking good so far. Could you please post it as the answer?

Comment: I believe the best way to go about this problem is to use `test.+?(?=\s*test|$)` (with `gs` modifiers) and then check which matches contain `XX12QW`.

Comment: @Gurman Did you have time to check my anwser? If it is of no use, I will delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pure regex solution is possible, but it would be best to split with `test` and grab the item that contains `XX12QW` from the array and appen the `test` at the start:

```js
var s = "test \nabc def \ntest 123 \ntest pqr \nXX12QW\njkl XX12QW hjas \n12asd23 test bxs";
var res = s.split('test').slice(1)   // Split with 'test' and remove 1st item
       .filter(function(x) {return ~x.indexOf("XX12QW");}) // Keep those with XX12QW
       .map(function(y) {return ("test"+y).trim();});  // Append test back and trim
console.log(res);
```

A single regex solution can look like

```
/test(?:(?!test)[^])*?XX12QW[^]*?(?=\s*test)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qORC29/1)

**Details**

- `test` - a literal `test` substring
- `(?:(?!test)[^])*?` - a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) matching any char, 0+ chars, as few as possible, other than those starting a `test` char sequence
- `XX12QW` - a literal `XX12QW` substring
- `[^]*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible, up to (and excluding...)
- `(?=\s*test)` - 0+ whitespaces followed with the `test` substring.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks a lot for that link to tempered greedy token. I didn't know about it. Learnt a new thing today.